# How are images in MNIST dataset transformed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

In the [cnn_mnist.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) example, the script starts by loading the train and test data as you can see from lines `120` to `124`. When I print `print(train_data.shape)`, I get `(55000, 784)`. Thus, I interpreted the train set here having `55000` images each of dimension=`784`. My question is: How is the dimension generated? Is it by transforming each image in MNIST dataset into 1D vector? I want to understand this point because I want to feed this script with my own collection of handwriting images I collected.

Thank you

Comment: @Li357 Thank you very much ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can understand it simply, As every image in MNIST data is 28x28px, so when we convert our image into 1D matrix, its size becomes 28x28=784.

> MNIST image size is 28 × 28 pixel, so it is represented as 784 1-d array.

each value in the matrix represents the value between 0 to 255.

Comment: So each row represents a single image flattened from 2D (28*28) to 1D (1,784) row-wise, is that correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Read more about it from here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-10-Visualizing-MNIST/